# Use custom keys in Routing files

Tags: routes, symfony

Is there anyway to add custom key/value pairs in the Routing file of a Symfony2 project and then read it in the controller?

For example:

```
AcmeDemoBundle_Default_hello:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:hello }
    SomeCustomKey: CustomValue
```

I want to use these key/value pairs to add some dynamic behavior to one of my projects. For example, I can read all the routes with a custom key/value pair and show them to the user, to be used in dynamic menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the method proposed @alessandro1997 works fine, I found another way to do this (which I think is better):

You can add key/value pairs to the `options` section of a route.
It is better because it does not clutter with parameters which are passed to the controller (I think so, correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: I agree with that answer. But could you please give an example of how you accessed the path's options (in your controller or view)?

Answer (score 6):

I feel its a better idea to use options as they are not added to route params. And you can also access these options in your controller.

In routing.yml file:

```
demo_page:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: DemoBundle:Default:index }
    options:
        key: value
```

And in your controller you can access options like this:

```
    /**
     * @var $router \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router
     */
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $routeCollection = $router->getRouteCollection();

    /**
     * @var $route \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
     */
    $route = $routeCollection->get($this->getRequest()->get('_route'));

    $allOptions = $route->getOptions();

    $specificOption = $route->getOption('key');
```

Comment: Is possible to access this variables from twig? (without pass them from the controller)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the key/value pair to the `defaults` section and then read it in the controller:

```
AcmeDemoBundle_Default_hello:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:hello, key: value }
```

And in the controller:

```
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('key');
```

It should work.